# CSS issues with "ionic run"

Tags: android, ios, css, angular, ionic-framework

I'm developing an app with Ionic 3. 
When running "ionic serve" everything works fine. 
If I run "ionic cordova run [platform]" (or double-click on index.html) some CSS is broken, sliders for example.

There something can I do to understand what is happening?

Comment: I dont see an ionic run command in [the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands.html)... which cli are you using?

Comment: @SurajRao you're right, I mean "ionic cordova run [<platform>]"